# Notifications with MKStoreKit

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

I'm using MKStoreKit for auto-renewable subscriptions and everything is working fine, but I don't know what do these Notifications do. (`kSubscriptionsPurchasedNotification`and `kSubscriptionsInvalidNotification`).

When I call them in `ViewDidLoad` or `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` functions, their corresponding methods are called but `if([MKStoreManager isFeaturePurchased:@"myFeature"])` always returns false and enters in else statement. So why this happens and what's the benefit of using them?

Secondly, like I said I'm using auto-renewable subscriptions, when the subscribed period has expired the subscription is not renewed automatically, the user has to press again to login to my app and subscribe manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with subscriptions you should be using :

```
[[MKStoreManager sharedManager] isSubscriptionActive:@"myFeature"];
```

rather than : *[MKStoreManager isFeaturePurchased:@"myFeature"]*

```
isFeaturePurchased:
```

is used to check "Consumable" in-app purchases.